# Get Permission denied running pycharm.sh

Tags: python, pycharm

It's wierd.

I just dowload the pycharm package from http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/, unpack the tar.gz file to a directory in my $HOME directory and run pycharm.sh. The file and folder are mine, so it's not a chmod problem.

Nevertheless I have message:
bash: ./pycharm.sh: Permission denied.

What's happening?

Update: output of ls command:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 caco dialout 5618 Abr  3 10:32 pycharm.sh
```

Update: I think it's probably a matter of conflict with the file server my account is using. The server is MAC OS X, and I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 in a local net. I don't know to say in details what is going on, but certanly it's this. Works if my account is linked with local file system.

Comment: Owning is not enough, you also need execute permissions. What does `ls -l pycharm.sh` say?

Comment: I forgot to say. Yes I have execute permission. `ls -l pycharm.sh` says `-rwxr-xr-x 1 caco dialout 5618 Abr  3 10:32 pycharm.sh`

Comment: Update your *question* with the output of the `ls` command, rather than leaving it in a comment.

Comment: another wild guess: is there a shebang in `pycharm.sh`?

Comment: Yes, there is #!/bin/sh

Comment: FWIW, I downloaded pycharm and unpacked it using `tar -zxvf pycharm...` and it works for me (tm). What is the output of `ls -l /bin/sh`?

Comment: also. my properties of pycharm is `-rwxr-xr-x 1 xx xx 5.5K Apr  3 15:32 pycharm.sh*` i.e. same user and group. That is not the case in your output. you have `caco dialout`. Perhaps a `chown` will solve the issue?

Comment: Output of `ls -l /bin/sh` is `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Dez 18 17:16 /bin/sh -> dash`

Comment: @FredrikPihl, I don't have the group `caco`, in my system. So It doesn't possible to change group to `caco`. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: No, I meant that you should change the group to your own default-group for all files.